# Syntax error: then but then

Tags: delphi

Não sei o que esta acontecendo, cada linha apresenta um erro diferente.

Falta `then` ou passa `then`, em outros casos falta `;`

```
  program Untitled;
    var
    peso:real;
    altura:real;
    idade:integer;
    begin
    writeln('digite seu peso');
      read(peso);
    writeln('digite sua altura');
       read(altura);
    writeln('digite sua idade');
        read(idade);
    if(peso / altura * altura <= 16)then

       writeln('voce esta com magreza extrema')
       else if(peso / altura * altura) >=16) and (peso / altura * altura) <=17)

        writeln('voce esta com magreza moderada')

        else if(peso / altura* altura) in (17..18.5)
             writeln('voce esta com magreza leve')
        else if(peso / altura * altura  >= 18,5) and (peso / altura * altura <= 25)
             writeln('voce esta saudavel')
        else if(peso / altura * altura >=25) and (peso / altura * altura <=30)
            writeln('voce esta com sobre peso')
        else if(peso / altura * altura >=30) and (peso / altura * altura <=35)
            writeln('voce esta com grau de obesidade I procure ajuda')
        else if(peso / altura * altura >=35) and ((peso / altura * altura <=40)
            writeln('voce esta com grau de obesidade II procure ajuda')
        else if(peso / altura * altura >=40) and (peso / altura * altura <=45)
            wirteln('voce esta com grau de obsidade III procure ajuda')


    end
```

Error log:

```
'THEN' expected but ')' found

')' expected but '..' found

';' expected but end of file found
```

Como corrigir estes erros de Sintaxe?

Comment: Esclarece melhor a tua duvida, nao é so pores aqui código e esperares que as pessoas te resolvam as coisas

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues, no Delphi é isso mesmo, pouco temos a explicar! A Pergunta esta claríssima para mim! Executando o código dele o titulo da pergunta esta evidente!

Comment: "Executando o código dele" entao eu cada vez que tiver um problema ponho aqui o código chapado e voces que me resolvam o problema :P Só queria dizer que faltou esforço em tentar perceber a origem do problema :) Cumprimentos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema todo começa na indentação, a IDE XE10.2.2 não conseguiu reajustar seu código.
Então fiz na mão. Porem, vale lembrar que testes no Delphi devem ser terminados com o `then`, independente da quantidade de testes.

Ainda existe problemas no Códigos na separação dos testes que estão em conjunto com o `and`.

Cálculos matemáticos devem ser separados por `()` para evitar resultados inesperados.

Ex:

```
if a * b = c then
```

É igual a:

```
if ((a * b) = c) then
```

São iguais para a mesma finalidade, mas o segundo exemplo esta mais organizado e pronto para um segundo unificado:

```
if ((a * b) = c) and
   ((a * b) > 0) then
```

Array no Delphi é tratado com `[` e não com `(`:

Troque `in (17..18.5)` por `in [17..18.5]` "aqui ainda existe um problema, no array não pode usar o Extended, apenas Integer, logo, teremos que extender o teste com um `and` a mais"

No Delphi os valores "monetários" são tratados com `.` e não com `,`:

Troque `18,5` por `18.5`

Reorganizando seu código ficaria assim:

```
  Writeln('digite seu peso');
  Read(peso);
  writeln('digite sua altura');
  read(altura);
  Writeln('digite sua idade');
  Read(idade);
  if (((peso / altura) * altura) <= 16) then
    Writeln('voce esta com magreza extrema')
  else if (((peso / altura) * altura) >= 16) and
          (((peso / altura) * altura) <= 17) then
    Writeln('voce esta com magreza moderada')
  else if (((peso / altura) * altura) >= 17) or
          (((peso / altura) * altura) <= 18.4) then
       Writeln('voce esta com magreza leve')
  else if (((peso / altura) * altura) >= 18.5) and
          (((peso / altura) * altura) <= 25) then
    Writeln('voce esta saudavel')
  else if (((peso / altura) * altura) >= 25) and
          (((peso / altura) * altura) <=30) then
    Writeln('voce esta com sobre peso')
  else if (((peso / altura) * altura) >= 30) and
          (((peso / altura) * altura) <= 35) then
    Writeln('voce esta com grau de obesidade I procure ajuda')
  else if (((peso / altura) * altura) >= 35) and
          (((peso / altura) * altura) <= 40) then
    Writeln('voce esta com grau de obesidade II procure ajuda')
  else if (((peso / altura) * altura) >= 40) and
          (((peso / altura) * altura) <= 45) then
    Writeln('voce esta com grau de obesidade III procure ajuda');
```

Vale lembrar que uma função que retorne o resultado de `((peso / altura) * altura)` para uma variável seria ideal!

Comment: Se a resposta resolver o seu problema, marque-a como correta, dessa forma orienta a próxima pesquisa a uma solução mais rápida!

Comment: não, O `end` seria necessário se existisse um `begin` após o ultimo `then`.

Comment: Sleep(tempo_em_milesegundos)

Comment: detalhe: (peso / altura) * altura é sempre igual a peso. provavelmente a intenção era peso / (altura * altura)

Comment: outro detalhe: a variável idade não é utilizada